# scrape related elements in the same row of a table using selenium but without xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape this HTML using selenium and PhantomJS.  The row pattern repeats with Row 1 to N and I don't know how many rows there will be.

```
<table id="TableName">
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="Row 1">
        <td class="Details column">
        </td>
        <td class="More details column">
        </td>
        <td class="Extra details column">
            <div class="unique_information">
                <div class="print-only">ID # 1234</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="Numbers column">
            <div class="numbers-data">
                <div>
                    <label class="specific_number">123456</label>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </td>
        <td class="Numbers column">
            <div class="numbers-data">
                <div>
                    <label class="specific_number">345678</label>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </td>   
        <td class="Numbers column">
            <div class="numbers-data">
                <div>
                    <label class="specific_number">234567</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In this case I'm trying to find the largest class_by_name(specific_number) (ie. 345678) that could be in any of the "Number Columns" that is also in the same row associated with the specific "unique_information" that I am looking for (ie. 1234).

I'm not great at xpath, and I won't know the parent row that has that unique_information ahead of time (ie. could be in Row 1, 2, 3, etc)  so I'm struggling to come up with a contains statement that makes sure both are true.

Comment: The number might come from any row, but that row must contain the text 'ID # 1234'. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: If you don't want to use XPath, why did you add the XPath tag to your question?

Comment: I'm open to XPath, I'm just not very good at it, so it's harder for me to follow. I'd prefer a non XPath solution.

Comment: Bill yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def findLargestNumInRow(id):
    xpath = '//table[@id="TableName"]/tbody/tr[td[3][div/div[contains(text(),"{0}")]]]'.format(id)
    tds = driver
              // find row which unique_information contains given id
              .find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
              // find all number child td
              .find_elements_by_css_selector('td.Numbers')

    numbers = [ td.text * 1 for td in tds]
    return numbers.sort()[-1]

findLargestNumInRow('1234')
```

Comment: Yong, is that tied to the third column? (ie. td[3])  How would this change if 1234 could be in any of the columns?

Comment: Yes, tied to thrid column.  To suite for any column change to //table[@id="TableName"]/tbody/tr[td/div/div[contains(text(),"{0}")]]   if you can pre-know which column, it's better to use index to speed find

Comment: I also summarized the content inside of the table, so there is actually a lot more complex data including embeded tables, etc.  Does div/div imply the direct structure?  Sorry, I'm not very good at XPath.

Comment: yes, if the '1234' comes from an embeded table and it is a long path from td to the element which has the '1234',  you can try this //table[@id="TableName"]/tbody/tr[td//*[contains(.,'1234')]]

Comment: So that worked, I verifyed with Chrome that the xpath pulls up the table row.  I then just find the elements_by_class_name(specific_number) add them to an array and a do a max of the array.  Now, is there anyway to find that row without using xpath?  Had to ask because I stupidly put that in my title as kjhughes pointed out above

Comment: For css selector, it not support find elemen by text on element, only xpath support that,  if you not want to use xpath,  you have to iterator all row and find out which row contains that text in a loop, means more code and more execution time need.  For those by_id/by_name/by_class_name more less possible.

Comment: Thanks yong for the help.  Accepted this answer!